# Not getting all profile informations when verifying a google token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, omniauth, google-signin

I'm using omniauth on client-side to connect with a google account. Everything is working well, I'm able to get the id_token and some more informations such as the email, name, family_name, given_name etc...

Here is how I configured the provider in app/config/initializer/omniauth.rb :

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'], scope: "profile,email"
```

Then, as a test, to verify the authenticity of the id_token, using Postman I send a POST request such as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=x
```

replacing x by the id_token I got on my client

I get a valid answer such as :

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "at_hash": "xxx-xxx",
  "aud": "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "xxx",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "azp": "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "email": "xxx@gmail.com",
  "iat": "xxx",
  "exp": "xxx",
  "alg": "xxx",
  "kid": "xxx"
}
```

When I connected with my client, I allowed the application to access my profile informations and my email, and I've been following this tuto:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

who says :

```
 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
```

I can't figure out why I'm unable to get the 5 last fields

I'm working on an API and I'd like my API to be able to fill a User model by itself, only by getting the id_token.
I'm able to get those informations on the client-side but I think this is not the client job to send this extra informations to my API right?

Comment: what are the 5 fields you aren't getting? could you post the params hash?

Comment: I'm not getting "name", "picture", "given_name", "family_name" and "locale". I'm not sure I understand what you want, there is no params hash, the only param I provide is "id_token"

Comment: Am I understanding your question correctly? : You are able to obtain profile information on browser, but not server side with OmniAuth library. If so, how do you configure API endpoints to use OAuth? I'm not familiar with OmniAuth.

Comment: I'm talking about an API, but the problem is not here, I did not write the server side part of this feature yet. As long as the verification of the id_token is not working I'm not writing it. But it might be a problem with OmniAuth on the client side, where I set the provider in app/config/initializer/omniauth.rb it just seems like it does not take account of the "profile" scope

Comment: How does the client side work? Are you using Google Sign-In library?

Comment: Yes under the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem. @quest found the solution, it seems like I was just not using the right URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token calls don't include profile info... for that you muse use:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this with ruby there are 2 things i can suggest trying

1. Try adding your scopes as an array ["profile", "email"]
2. Add an extra parameter fetch_basic_profile from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just tried both your suggestions and it's still the same result :/